# Is there a character ring for quantum groups?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, wess-zumino-witten

It is a well known fact that for any (reasonable) group $G$, the character ring and the representation ring are isomorphic,
$$
\chi_{R_1}(g)\chi_{R_2}(g)=\chi_{R_1\otimes R_2}(g),\qquad g\in G
$$

Is there a generalization of this for chiral algebras? If we let $\chi_\lambda(z,\tau)$ be the characters at modulus $\tau$ and fugacities $z\in \mathfrak g$ (i.e., the torus trace of a primary $\lambda$ in a WZW model), is there an expression of the form
$$
\chi_\lambda(z,\tau)\chi_\mu(z,\tau)\overset?=\chi_{\mu\times\lambda}(z,\tau)
$$
where $\mu\times\lambda$ denotes fusion? (I tried to check this equality in a simple example and it seems to fail; is there a *version* of this equality that is true? After all, the characters obviously "know" the fusion rules via the Verlinde formula. On the other hand, it is not clear to me how this equality could possibly hold if $\lambda,\mu$ are not mutually local...)

Comment: Fusion isn't commutative but multiplication is, which seems to imply your formula can't hold in the general case, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Fusion *is* commutative, no? This question is in the context of chiral algebras/WZW models, where the fusion category is actually braided. I agree that general fusion categories need not be commutative, but the specific type that appear in rational CFTs are in fact commutative. Or am I saying something silly?